# Comparison method violates its general contract java7

Tags: java, comparison, comparator

I know many answers have answered my question. In my code, the exception said that "Comparison method violates its general contract", but i do not know my compare method how violates its general contract.This is my code:

```
public static List<Entry<Integer, Double>> sortMap(
    Map<Integer, Double> curMap, final boolean isDesc) {
    List<Entry<Integer, Double>> res = new ArrayList<Entry<Integer, Double>>();
    for (Entry<Integer, Double> iter : curMap.entrySet()) {
        res.add(iter);
    }
    Collections.sort(res, new Comparator<Entry<Integer, Double>>() {
        public int compare(Entry<Integer, Double> o1,
                Entry<Integer, Double> o2) {
            if (o1.getValue() == o2.getValue()) {
                return 0;
            } else if (o1.getValue() > o2.getValue()) {
                return isDesc ? -1 : 1;
            }
            return isDesc ? 1 : -1;
        }
    });
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple subtle things going on here. This is not the usual "broken comparator" problem seen elsewhere on Stack Overflow. Although this comparator is indeed broken, it's pretty hard to see.

The first issue is that the comparator is essentially responsible for comparing `Double` values, that is, boxed `double` values. Whereas the `>` operator will perform automatic unboxing and do a numeric comparison of the contained values, the `==` operator will test reference equality. In general,

```
Double.valueOf(1.23) == Double.valueOf(1.23) // WARNING: reference comparison, not numeric!
```

will be `false`. If you really wanted to test numeric equality of `Double` values, you'd have to do

```
if (o1.getValue().doubleValue() == o2.getValue.doubleValue()) ...
```

This would mostly work if your input contains only actual numeric values. I suspect, though, that your input contains `NaN` values, which have obscure (even nonsensical) behavior. In particular, comparing `NaN` to any numeric value is false, and `NaN` compares not equal to itself! This violates all sorts rules about numeric comparisons; indeed, `NaN` is unordered with respect to real numbers. This is why the sort algorithm breaks when it encounters `NaN` values.

(`NaN` is the result of dividing 0.0 by 0.0, among other things.)

There is a method [`Double.compare(double d1, double d2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-) that handles `NaN` reasonably; it sorts `NaN` values above `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`. (It also distinguishes positive zero from negative zero, but that's unlikely to have caused your problem.) There is a companion method [`Double.compareTo(Double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo-java.lang.Double-) that compares boxed `Double` values.

I'd rewrite your comparator like this:

```
Collections.sort(res, new Comparator<Entry<Integer, Double>>() {
    public int compare(Entry<Integer, Double> o1,
                       Entry<Integer, Double> o2) {
        if (isDesc) {
            return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1);
        } else {
            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2);
        }
    }
}
```

Since `Double` is `Comparable` itself, in Java 8 you can avoid writing your own comparator by using a utility method on `Map.Entry`. You can also use the `sort()` default method on `List` which will be faster in general:

```
if (isDesc) {
    res.sort(Map.Entry.<Integer,Double>comparingByValue().reversed());
} else {
    res.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
}
```

(Unfortunately, the type inference doesn't quite work, so you have to provide a "type witness" in order to get the reversed comparator.)

Finally, you can use the "diamond" operator and the `ArrayList` copy constructor to copy the map entries much more concisely. The rewritten routine looks like this:

```
public static List<Entry<Integer, Double>> sortMap(
        Map<Integer, Double> curMap, final boolean isDesc) {
    List<Entry<Integer, Double>> res = new ArrayList<>(curMap.entrySet());

    if (isDesc) {
        res.sort(Map.Entry.<Integer,Double>comparingByValue().reversed());
    } else {
        res.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
    }

    return res;
}
```